# Need help to validate decimal number with specific length using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The number of digits that need to present in a number is predefined , i need a regular expression/function to validate the input number.

Example:  if length is (0,2) then the number that should allow like:

```
0.0      --true,
0        -- true,
000.0000 - true,
0.2      --true,
0.200    --true,
1.2      -- false,
0.22     -- true,
0.02     -- true,
.2       -- true,
.99      -- true
```

if length is (2,2)  then the number that should allow like:

```
0.0      --true,
0        -- true,
000.0000 - true,
0.2      --true,
0.200    --true,
1.2      -- true,
0.22     -- true,
0.02     -- true,
.2       -- true,
.99      -- true,
12.21    -- true,
0099.3200-- true,
80.080   --true,
80.80    --true,
8.088    --false,
09.9     --true,
9.0      --true,
5        --true,
89       --true
```

and so on.   Any idea/suggestion/code/help will appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the failure states, please provide more examples that would fail, and explain the reasoning.

Comment: 1>if length is (0,2)- here the values that should allow like-  before decimal there will only 0 and after decimal the values length will 2 (maximum excluding the right hand 0's)

Comment: 2> if length is (2,2) then the number of digits before decima will 2 excluding left hand 0's and the after decimal  number of digits will 2 excluding right hand 0's -ie :  0022.2200  is valid  but 220.003 is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Broad outline of one possible approach:

1. Validate the data to make sure you are working with numbers, or strings consisting only of digits and periods.
2. Cast the variable as a string (x+'' will cast x as a string)
3. Split the string on the period. (var array = x.split('.');
4. Verify that the split array length is not greater than 2 (if it is greater than two, there was more than one . in the string)
5. Cast each half as a number (x*1 will cast x as a number)
6. Verify that each half is less than (10 ^ # of digits for that half)
7. If the tests in 4 or 6 fail, the number fails.  Else, it passes.

Comment: And watch out for numbers that are sufficiently large or small as to require exponential notation!

Comment: Also since the conversion to string will implicitly represent the number without excess leading or trailing zeros, that's probably all that you have to do.

Comment: any idea to remove the trailing 0's from decimal part?

Comment: Yeah, conversion to number takes care of the leading/trailing 0s.  You could also strip them with a regex and then test the length of the string, which should then be <= # of digits for that half.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically avoid RegExp for something like this, but a pattern like the following could work where `a` and `b` are from `(a, b)`:

```
/^0*[0-9]{0,a}(?:\.[0-9]{0,b}0*)?$/
```

The breakdown:

```
^ - beginning of string
0* - zero or more zeros
[0-9]{0,a} - 0 to a digits*
(?: - start of a non-capturing container
\. - a period character
[0-9]{0,b} - 0 to b digits*
0* - zero or more zeros
)? - 0 or 1 of the non-capturing containers
$ - end of the string
```

<sub>*(`\d` could be used in place of `[0-9]`, but i wanted to keep the letters as variables)</sub>

You'd need to build your RegEx from a string if you want dynamic numbers, but if they're static, then you could hard-code it:

```
(2,2)
/^0*[0-9]{0,2}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2}0*)?$/
```

Comment: As a note, be careful if you're converting numbers, such as `072`, because they'll be interpreted as Octal due to the leading `0`.